# convert base64 image to jpg then upload to server not working

Tags: php, base64

I am new to base64 and I have never needed to convert it so I am not sure what is going on here. I have my base64 string in `$socialmedia_image`. I create a random file name with `rand`. I plug it into the function which I got off stack and....nothing. It does not convert or transfer over with `move_uploaded_file` and I have no idea who to check for an error.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
///// base64 string /////
$socialmedia_image = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUg.....";

$rand = rand(000000000000000,999999999999999);
$output_file = $rand.".jpg";

$socialmedia_image = base64_to_jpeg( $socialmedia_image, $output_file );

function base64_to_jpeg($base64_string, $output_file) {
    $ifp = fopen( $output_file, 'w' ); 
    $data = explode( ',', $base64_string );
    fwrite( $ifp, base64_decode( $data[ 1 ] ) );
    fclose( $ifp ); 
    return $output_file; 
}
move_uploaded_file($socialmedia_image, "../tickets/attachments/".$output_file);
```

Comment: There appears to be some miss understanding here... `move_uploaded_file()` moves a file that has been uploaded as part of the request. That is _not_ the case in your example, you did not upload a file. Instead you simply want to move the file you created I assume, you can use the `rename()` function for that.

Comment: so what is the `base64_to_jpeg` function returning to me that I can work with?

Comment: Look at the code you yourself posted! It obviously returns the name of the file you told it to create. . Whether it actually created that file as instructed is another thing, that depends on file system permissions for example. Check in the file system if that file has been created. If not, then check your http servers error log file for a clear error message.

Comment: ...or simply store the base64 data (after you have removed the first part) in the correct location directly. No need to create one file just to move/rename it directly after it.

Comment: ahhhhhh I get it now. The function creates the file in the directory that it is working in..... ok that makes sense now. I never looked at the directory I was working in to see if the files were there. Thanks man. Make it an answer and Ill mark it.

Answer (score -1):

How about that?

```
file_put_contents($output_file, $data);
```